# Mailgun emails not sending from Laravel 8 Valet app

Tags: php, laravel, email, mailgun, laravel-8

Here's my relevant `.env`:

```
MAIL_MAILER=mailgun
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailgun.org
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=null
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"
MAILGUN_DOMAIN=https://api.mailgun.net/v3/mail.example.com
MAILGUN_SECRET=fb...a1
```

**Note:** I use example.com as an example above, but I've put my actual domain name there. I do not get any errors from the Laravel app, and I do not see anything in the logs on the Mailgun dashboard. My domain is verified. `fb...a1` is also the redacted API code, I of course use my full API code I get from the mailgun dashboard.

`config/mail.php`:

```php
<?php

return [
    'default' => env('MAIL_MAILER', 'mailgun'),

    'mailers' => [
        'mailgun' => [
            'transport' => 'mailgun',
        ],
    ],
];
```

`config/services.php`:

```php
'mailgun' => [
    'domain' => env('MAILGUN_DOMAIN'),
    'secret' => env('MAILGUN_SECRET'),
    'endpoint' => env('MAILGUN_ENDPOINT', 'api.mailgun.net'),
],
```

In my controller I have:

```php
$email = $validated['email']; // I've verified this is my actual email
Mail::to($email)->send(new OrderCreated());
```

`app/Mail/OrderCreated.php`:

```php
namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class OrderCreated extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    public function build()
    {
        return $this
            ->from('no-reply@example.com')
            ->markdown('emails.order-created');
    }
}
```

And finally, `resources/views/emails/order-created.blade.php`:

```php
@component('mail::message')
# Order Confirmation

This email is  test.
@endcomponent
```

I'm using Laravel 8.14.0 and Valet 2.13.0, so I'm testing it locally with an https://my-app.test domain. The app is using InertiaJS, in case that makes any difference. The controller code runs without error, but I see no logs on my mailgun dashboard and the email never arrives in my inbox. I have no idea what's wrong or how to debug this.

**UPDATE:**

I've noticed if I set `MAILGUN_DOMAIN` and `MAILGUN_SECRET` to `null`, I get the same behaviour as above. If I set `MAILGUN_DOMAIN` to a nonsense value like `abcd` I get the following error:

```
GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException
Client error: `POST https://api.mailgun.net/v3/abcd/messages.mime` resulted in a `401 UNAUTHORIZED` response: Forbidden
```

And if I set `MAILGUN_SECRET` to `abcd` it works as originally described (no error, but also no email).

Comment: Have you checked the correct endpoint for your domain in your Mailgun account? If your domain was created in their EU endpoint and you try to use it with the US endpoint, it may fail silently just like you described.

Comment: MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=null - this may be your issue, I know you are setting it in the class however Ive had issues with this in the past. make sure its the right domain as your mailgun one also.

Comment: @EnricoDias I created it with the US endpoint, and https://api.mailgun.net/v3/... is what's appearing for me in the dashboard.

Comment: @MichaelMano I've set MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS and it seems to make no difference. What do you mean by making sure it's the right domain as my mailgun one? My domain is set up as mail.example.com, and I've tried both no-reply@exmaple.com and no-reply@mail.example.com.

Comment: @chipit24 mail.example.com is what i meant. but i guess thats not the issue, driver set to smtp? have you got guzzle installed?

Comment: @MichaelMano I've set `MAIL_MAILER=mailgun` and in `config/mail.php` I have `'default' => env('MAIL_MAILER', 'mailgun'),`

Comment: I've tested it with SMTP and it appears to be the same, so maybe this is more specific to Mailgun and Laravel/Valet? I've installed `guzzlehttp/guzzle` as per the Laravel mail docs.

Comment: Well herp derp, I was using the wrong value for `MAILGUN_DOMAIN` *facepalm*. I thought it was the API endpoint they gave me, and conflated those terms.

Answer (score 0):

These days I've worked with mailgun. It was on Laravel 7, and it worked perfectly. I dont think that it will cause a problem for v8.
Actually I've sent emails from controller, but you can implement the same for you as you want.
So I'll share my experience anyway.

**.env**

```
#MAIL_DRIVER=mailgun
MAIL_MAILER=mailgun
MAIL_HOST="smtp.mailgun.org"
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME="postmaster@sandbox********************************.mailgun.org"
MAIL_PASSWORD="123456"
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
MAILGUN_DOMAIN="sandbox********************************.mailgun.org"
MAILGUN_SECRET="key-********************************"
MAIL_FROM_NAME="ProjectName"
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS="no-reply@yourfuturesite.com"
MAIL_ENV=test
MAIL_TEST="recipient@yourfuturesite.com"
#MAIL_LOG_CHANNEL
#MAILGUN_ENDPOINT="api.eu.mailgun.net"
```

**config/mail.php**

```
<?php

return [
    'default' => env('MAIL_MAILER'),
    'mailers' => [
        'smtp' => [
            'transport' => 'smtp',
            'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.mailgun.org'),
            'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),
            'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),
            'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),
            'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),
            'timeout' => null,
            'auth_mode' => null,
        ],
        'ses' => [
            'transport' => 'ses',
        ],
        'mailgun' => [
            'transport' => 'mailgun',
            'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.mailgun.org'),
            'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),
            'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),
            'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),
            'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),
            'timeout' => null,
            'auth_mode' => null,
        ],
        'postmark' => [
            'transport' => 'postmark',
        ],
        'sendmail' => [
            'transport' => 'sendmail',
            'path' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',
        ],
        'log' => [
            'transport' => 'log',
            'channel' => env('MAIL_LOG_CHANNEL'),
        ],
        'array' => [
            'transport' => 'array',
        ],
    ],
    'from' => [
        'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS'),
        'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME'),
    ],
    'markdown' => [
        'theme' => 'default',
        'paths' => [
            resource_path('views/vendor/mail'),
        ],
    ],
    // CUSTOM CONFIGS
    'mail_env' => env('MAIL_ENV'), // 'local' for testing via mailgun, 'production' for all mails
    'mail_test' => env('MAIL_TEST'), // test email for 'local' testing
    // ADDITIONAL UNNECESSARY CONFIGS
    // 'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',
    // 'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -t-i',
    // 'pretend' => false,
    // 'log_channel' => env('MAIL_LOG_CHANNEL'),
    // 'pretend' => false,
];
```

**config/services.php (the same as you have)**

**Controller**

```
try {
    $name = array_key_exists('first_name', $email_data) ? $email_data['first_name'] : $email_data['name'];

    Mail::send('emails.confirm-registration', [
        'role' => $email_data['role'],
        'name' => $name,
        'email' => $email_data['email'],
        'confirm_registration' => route('front.auth.confirm_registration', ['registration_token' => $email_data['registration_token']]),
    ], function ($message) use ($email_data, $name) {
        $to = (config('mail.mail_env') == 'prod' || config('mail.mail_env') == 'production') ? $email_data['email'] : config('mail.mail_test');
        $message
            ->subject(config('app.name') . ": Email Confirmation")
            ->from(config('mail.from.address'), config('mail.from.name'))
            ->to($to, $name);
    });

    return true;
}
catch(\Exception $e) {
    // TODO: report all the "$e->message"s like this
    return false;
}
```

**resources/views/emails/confirm-registration.php**

```
<a href="{{ route('front.main') }}" target="_blank">
    <img label="logo" alt="{{ config('app.name') }}"
         src="{{ $message->embed(public_path('images/logo.svg')) }}" width="128" height="96">
</a>
<p>{{ $name }}</p>
<p>{{ $confirm_registration }}</p>
<p>© {{ date("Y") == 2020 ? '2020' : '2020-' . date("Y") }} {{ config('app.name') }}</p>
```

This is just my example, so there you may need to replace as you want.
Just pay attention to "config/mail.php" file. I think there you need to set some additional props. (Also don't forget to reload your cache after these last config changes: "php artisan config:cache")

Comment: Thanks, I figured out I was using the wrong value for `MAILGUN_DOMAIN`. Everything else in my original config was fine.